# Spring MVC: How to direct to a page outside the current controller class after an asynchronous process

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have perhaps a rather stupid question,
The situation is, 
1. I have a controller class which starts an asynchronous process and then directs to a waiting page. 
2. When the asynchronous process is done (no interaction is involved), it will publish an event. 
3. I have an event listener which listens to this event and by receiving it should direct the current waiting page to a page saying that the process is done.
But the problem is, the event listener is outside the controller class, how can I trigger the directing inside my event listener?

Comment: How does the "waiting" page communicate with the server? Are you polling? Using something like Comet?

Comment: I think I don't have any communication between "waiting" page and the server, it's only a static page. Maybe that's the reason I am asking... I am too new to the mvc world ;P

Comment: That's not an MVC question, it's a basic Web question.

Comment: Then maybe could you point me to a certain possible solution source I could dig in to solve this?